# How do I delete a file in my GitHub repository?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

How do I remove a file from my GitHub repository?
[Here is a screenshot of the file in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBxaQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Click on it, then you'll see a delete icon on the right side of the code header.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file which you want by using your IDE and push it again to your target repository with a proper commit. This is the safe way, I know.